# Jmeter- backend listner influxdb

Tags: jmeter, influxdb

I am running using jmeter 2.13
created test plan with thread group and backend listner.[backend listner jmeter](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9uh9f.png)

up docker image for influxdb ( tutum/influxdb). I am able to access influxdb dashboard.

I made changes in /config/config.toml.
added following in config.toml

```
[[graphite]]
enabled = true
bind-address = ":8086"
protocol = "tcp"
consistency-level = "one"
separator = "."
database = "jmeter"
```

I am not able to get data within jmeter database in influxdb after I run jmeter test cases.
Jmeter generates report with 200 code.
Please help to resolve this issue.

Comment: Tried with bind-address = ":2003"
facing same problem

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I used windows solution but I think it Should be similar.

1. Install InfluxDB with a new conf file. I did a copy of the default and overwrite the below properties algon with [data] path.In my case was as below

`[data]
  enabled = true
  dir = "C:\\software\\influxdb-1.0.2-1\\data"
  wal-dir = "C:\\software\\influxdb-1.0.2-1\\data\\wa`

And run inflix with this configuration.
`$influxd -config <path to file.conf>`.

This file has the graphite listener opened and linkened to DB

```
[[graphite]] 
enabled = true 
database = "jmeter" 
bind-address = ":2003"
#protocol = "tcp"
# consistency-level = "one"
```

Later activate the security because Grafana needs it. I suposse you want to see graphs.

```
[http]
enabled = true
bind-address = ":8086"
auth-enabled = true
```

2. Run Influx and using the browser add databases jmeter,grafana. Do not forget to add one administrative user. You can use QueryTemplate for these tasks. So 3 steps
   create two databases and at least one user with password.
3. Ensure Jmeter have Assertions to distinguish retult of the test and backednListender

Answer (score 0):

- You are able to access the InfluxDB - admin interface. But do you get the list of tables/measurements when you `Show Measurements` for your DB?
- If it shows the measurement, only the data is not shown, there is a chance that Jmeter's machine time is ahead of InfluxDB time.
- If it does not show the measurements, How do you run the docker image? Do you expose all the ports?
- My config file is as shown below. Update the config and restart InfluxDB and try again.

  ```
  [[graphite]]
  enabled = true
  bind-address = ":2003"
  database = "jmeter"
  #protocol = "tcp"
  #consistency-level = "one"
  #separator = "."
  ```